# Uploading Asset Doesn't Clear GraphQl Cache with VueJS/Axios

Tags: craft3, cache, graphql

**Context:** 
I have a VueJS method that uses a form and Axios to upload an asset to an entry's asset field.
The method successfully uploads the asset to the entry, and I can prove that fact via the CraftCMS admin interface. So this works.

**Problem:**
I then have another VueJS method that calls on CraftCMS' GraphQL service to list the assets in the entry's asset field. This works, and returns the assets. **But** if I add more assets using my VueJS/Axios method above, the assets are added just fine (as confirmed on the CraftCMS admin side), but the GraphQL cache is not updated. So when I refresh the page and make another call to GraphQL, it never shows the new asset(s) unless I manually clear the GraphQL cache in the Craft CMS admin interface.

**Questions:**

1. Can I force the GraphQL cache to be cleared from some kind of javascript / Axios call, or some kind of Twig call on the same page as it loads?
2. Can I prevent GraphQL from caching?
3. Is this a GraphQL/CraftCMS bug?
4. Amy I crazy to think any of this?

Thanks for any ideas/help!

**VueJS Method to Load the Asset list**

```
  created () {
    //Define a global self variable
    var self = this;
    //Load our query
    var queryData = {query: '{entries(section:"caseStudy",id:{{entry.id}}) {...on caseStudy_caseStudy_Entry{id,csImages{id,url,}}}}'};
    //Get authorization
    var queryHeaders = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ABCDEFG'}};
    //Fetch data from the system using our query
    axios.post('/api', queryData, queryHeaders).then(function(queryResponse) {
        //Set the uploadAssets data.
        self.uploadedAssets = queryResponse.data.data.entries[0].csImages;                
      }).catch(function (queryError) {
        console.log(queryError);
    });        
  },
```

`self.uploadedAssets` Will contain the assets on the asset field as desired. But if I upload new assets using the following VueJS method, GraphQL won't see the new asset(s), but I can prove that they uploaded just fine bucasue in the CrafCMS admin side I can see the news asset(s) in the entry form.

**VueJS method to upload the asset to CraftCMS, which works fine.**

```
 uploadImage(event) {
  //Get the current form data
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('formCaseworkEdit'));
  //Upload the form data to CraftCMS
  axios.post('/', formData).then(function(response) {
      //Call a function to retrieve the new list of assets
      self.getNewImage(response, self);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
 },
```

`self.getNewImage(response, self);` Will run the same GraphQL Query from the `create()` function , but will return the "old" listing of assets. When I manually clear CraftCMS caches, this list returns the new items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, as they say, "There's a config setting for that" - :facepalm: - If you add the following to your `/config/general.php` file it will disable GraphQL caching completely:

```
  //Disable GraphQL Caching
  'enableGraphQlCaching' => false,
```

To reference it from a `.env` environment variable use this instead:

```
  // Disable GraphQL Caching from .env variables
  'enableGraphQlCaching' => (bool)getenv('ENABLE_GQL_CACHING'),
```

Got this info from the amazing folks over at **nystudio107** via this post:
https://nystudio107.com/blog/using-the-craft-cms-graphql-api-on-the-frontend

Ideally if there was a way to flush the GraphQL cache at the time I need it that would be more precise, but disabling the GraphQL cache all together solves the problem.

Comment: Just a hint, you don't have to disable caching altogether - you could create a module that watches for entry save events and flushed the cache afterward. [Simple example, untested.](https://gist.github.com/daltonrooney/e0f4e7217cc03fd8204a09e2db30209a)

Comment: Interesting approach @Dalton, I was trying to do this without creating custom modules as much as possible, but a module may be a more refined solution.